# "de plus en [x]" ou "de plus en plus [x]"

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, locutions

Je me trouvais sur l'article wikipédia français à propos des particules grammatiques et j'ai constaté [une curieuse tournure](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_(grammaire)#:%7E:text=Cependant,%20au%20fur%20et%20%C3%A0%20mesure%20que%20la%20linguistique%20s%E2%80%99est%20orient%C3%A9e%20vers%20une%20approche%20de%20plus%20en%20pragmatique):

> Cependant, au fur et à mesure que la linguistique s’est orientée vers une approche de plus en pragmatique, ...

Je croyais que la formulation correcte était "de plus en *plus*" avec un deuxième "plus", non ? Est-ce c'est une faute de frappe par le/la wikipédien(ne), ou bien est-ce qu'il y a en effet des fois où l'on préfère "de plus en [adj.]" à "de plus en plus [adj.]" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cependant, au fur et à mesure que la linguistique s’est orientée vers une approche de plus en pragmatique, ce sont ces mots qu’on a étudiés en tant que particules.

Ce n'est pas une faute d'inattention; on ne dit pas autre chose que « de plus en plus X » si on a l'intention d'exprimer le fait que quelque chose n'arrête pas de grandir, de s'intensifier, de croitre, etc. Il y a bien cette possibilité,  dans le présent cas si « pragmatique » n'est conçu qu'en tant qu'adjectif). Mais dans l'article, il s'agit d'un nom, un nom de création relativement récente (William James (1842-1910)) dans le domaine de la linguistique ([pragmatique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatique_(linguistique))) . Le sens est donc celui-ci : « la linguistique s'est orientée petit à petit vers une approche qui doit être considérée comme étant en plus.

On peut dire cependant que le style n'est pas clair; on peut aussi penser à l'interprétation suivante : « au fur et à mesure que la linguistique s'est orientée vers de nouvelles approches en pragmatique ».

Comment: Ahhh merci - je vois maintenant la petite ambiguïté qui me posait problème. J'apprécie beaucoup votre explication claire et approfondie ˆˆ

Answer (score 1):

*Est-ce c'est une faute de frappe par le/la wikipédien(ne), ou bien est-ce qu'il y a en effet des fois où l'on préfère "de plus en [adj.]" à "de plus en plus [adj.]" ?*

Ni l'un ni l'autre, ce n'est ni une coquille, ni une variante de la tournure « de plus en plus ».

Pour comprendre le sens de la phrase, on peut y substituer quelques mots comme suit :

> Cependant, au fur et à mesure que Mark Verstappen s’est orienté vers une victoire de plus en championnat de Formule 1, ...

Comment: « … s’est orientée vers une approche de plus **,** en pragmatique **,** ... » avec une "**,**" c'est compréhensible, sinon, ça perturbe [grave] la lecture et l'attention d'un *Hexagonal* … À moins que le contexte précédent n'induise cette tournure.

Comment: @Personne Le *fur et à mesure* met l'esprit du lecteur dans une disposition où *de plus en plus* est plausible. Ceci combiné au fait que *pragmatique* est dans 99% des cas un adjectif fait que la phrase est en effet très trompeuse, seul le lien présent dans la page wikipedia permet de comprendre que c'est un substantif. On aurait pu écrire : *Cependant, au fur et à mesure que la linguistique se rapprochait de la pragmatique*.

Comment: … mille et une fois d'accord :-)